# overloading operator+ for struct without affecting the operands

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I would like to overload a plus operator for struct without affecting two operands.

Here is what I have done.

```
struct Board {   
    int m_len;
    int blk[BLK_MAX][BLK_MAX];
};

Board& operator+(const Board& b1, const Board& b2) {
    Board ret;
    for (int y = 0; y < N; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < N; x++) {
            ret.blk[y][x] = b1.blk[y][x] + b2.blk[y][x];
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

It may work fine, however, I don't feel right since the operator returns a local variable. I am not sure if this may cause memory corruption. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Just remove the `&` and return the struct by value.

Comment: And before you look at the answers bellow and panic at the expansive copy, know that C++ has implemented NRVO for years. Nowadays the standard even describes how it should behave. Even though it doesn't force implementations to always do it, it's practically law now that most indeed do it.

Comment: @Peter Hwang What is the magic variable N? And why is not set another magic variable - the data member m_len?

Comment: I forgot to mention it. it is an integer constant(like 20).

Comment: You are absolutely right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a better way to do this?

Sure there is, and it's extremely straightforward. Addition computes a new *value.* It should therefore return a *value* (and not a reference):

```
Board operator+(const Board& b1, const Board& b2) {
    Board ret;
    for (int y = 0; y < N; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < N; x++) {
            ret.blk[y][x] = b1.blk[y][x] + b2.blk[y][x];
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Is there any possibility that the return value is corrupted by others? I am still suspicious since the local variable "ret" goes outside of the scope.

Comment: @PeterHwang - Do you have the same worry when you return an `int` by value?

Comment: @PeterHwang it does not, everything happens as if a copy was made when `operator+` exits.

Comment: So are you saying that returning struct is similar to returning int since it is "a value"?

Comment: @PeterHwang Of course. A value is a value (or "an object is an object"). In the case of `Board operator +()`, the returned value is an object initialised from `ret` (copied or moved).

Answer (score 2):

You should NOT return a local variable by reference.

You should just replace:

```
Board& operator+(const Board& b1, const Board& b2)
```

by:

```
Board operator+(const Board& b1, const Board& b2)
```